# Unable to display an image selected with ACTION_GET_CONTENT

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to display an image selected from the gallery in a image view using ACTION_GET_CONTENT, but it is not working for some reason.

activity_main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgViewTakePhoto"
        android:layout_width="270dp"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnTakePhoto"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTakePhoto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add Image"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.754" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.kt:

```
package com.example.fundamentals


import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        btnTakePhoto.setOnClickListener {
            Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT).also {
                it.type = "image/*"
                startActivityForResult(it,0)
            }
        }

    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if(requestCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == 0){
            val uri = data?.data
            imgViewTakePhoto.setImageURI(uri)
        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.fundamentals">

    <application

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

I am able to select the image from gallery but it is not being displayed in the image view i.e. imgViewTakePhoto .

I tried searching for answers here, some people said for Android 11 or higher, I have to add an external query to my manifest file but that did not worked either.

This was the query:

```
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
        </intent>
    </queries>
```

I don't think the version of Android is a problem here because I tried it again on Android 9, and it didn't work.

Comment: No. `<queries>` is nonsense. Probably the user selected an image with too high resolution. Select a small image.

Comment: I tried with a low resolution image and it didn't work. @blackapps

Comment: Hmmm.. there is nothing wrong with your code. It should just work if the resolution is not to big. How did you initialise `imgViewTakePhoto` ? You are not getting exceptions or a crash as otherwise you would have told us..

Comment: Yes, there are no exceptions or crashes. The selected image simply doesn't load in the image view. @blackapps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`startActivityForResult` has been deprecated in favour of newer and modern `registerForActivityResult` and ActivityResultContracts.

Therefore what you should rather be doing is firstly creating an ActivityResultLauncher like following :

```
private val getImage = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument()) {
     it?.let {
        imgViewTakePhoto.setImageURI(it)
    }
}
```

and then calling it inside your buttons on click like this :

```
btnTakePhoto.setOnClickListener {
    getImage.launch(arrayOf("image/*"))
}
```

Note that `registerForActivityResult` is supposed to be initialised before your activity comes into context due to the actual callback registering process which is why it should be directly instantiated as a variable before `onCreate` is called. If that is not the case then launching the result launcher would throw some state related exception.

Following is the final code for your MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val getImage = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument()) {
        it?.let {
            imgViewTakePhoto.setImageURI(it)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        btnTakePhoto.setOnClickListener {
            getImage.launch(arrayOf("image/*"))
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Also apart from all this, you should really be using viewbinding or databinding instead of kotlinx synthetic since that is deprecated aswell.